# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un método de una clase genérica en Java?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm

Estoy migrando mi código al paradigma MVVM. Dado que tengo varias Activity/Fragmentos he pensado en tener una clase utilitaria para las peticiones que hago a Firestore.

Generalmente yo hago las peticiones y mapeo el resultado a una clase. Y la finalidad de mi clase `FirestoreLiveData` es que reciba una determinada clase en parámetro, mapee el resultado y desde la vista poder usar esa clase en el `observe`.

El código funciona bien, pero en algunos contextos yo necesito hacer dos llamadas a Firestore.

- En una primera llamada se obtiene un objeto que sería mapeado a una clase llamada `Liturgia`
- En una segunda llamada se obtiene un objeto que sería **seteado** a la clase `Liturgia`.

De forma manual esto funciona bien. Pero no lo puedo incorporar a mi clase `FirestoreLiveData`, dado que aquí la clase es pasada como genérica.

Si observan el código, aquí estaría mapeando el resultado de la primera llamada a la clase `Liturgia` pasada en parámetro:

```
T item = (T) calSnapshot.toObject(clazz);
```

Pero luego yo quisiera hacer algo así:

```
item.setBreviario(....);
```

Pero no puedo hacerlo.

Creando la clase manualmente, sí es posible:

```
Breviario mBreviario = mLiturgia.getBreviario();
```

Aquí `mLiturgia` ha sido creada manualmente en la clase, a modo de prueba. Pero mi idea es poder pasar cualquier clase e invocar métodos de esa clase pasada en parámetro para agregarle contenido que viene en otra llamada a Firestore.

¿Es posible hacerlo?

Aquí dejo la parte relevante de mi clase utilitaria:

```
public class FirestoreLiveData<T> extends LiveData<T> {

    public static final String TAG = "FirestoreLiveData";

    private ListenerRegistration registration;

    private DocumentReference docRef;
    private Class clazz;
    private Liturgia mLiturgia;

    private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    public FirestoreLiveData(String mYear, String mMonth, String mDay, Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.docRef = db.collection(CALENDAR_PATH).document(mYear).collection(mMonth).document(mDay);
    }

    EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> eventListenerBis = new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }
            docRef.addSnapshotListener((calSnapshot, e1) -> {
                if ((calSnapshot != null) && calSnapshot.exists()) {
                    mLiturgia = calSnapshot.toObject(Liturgia.class);
                    T item = (T) calSnapshot.toObject(clazz);
                    Log.d("aaa",item.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                    //TODO Convertir en parámetro
                    String mField="lh.3";
                    DocumentReference dataRef = calSnapshot.getDocumentReference(mField);
                    if (e != null || dataRef == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener((DocumentSnapshot dataSnapshot) -> {
                        //mLiturgia.setBreviario(dataSnapshot.toObject(Breviario.class));
                        mLiturgia.setBreviario(dataSnapshot.toObject(Breviario.class));
                        Breviario mBreviario = mLiturgia.getBreviario();
                        Intermedia hi = mBreviario.getIntermedia();
                        MetaLiturgia mMeta = mLiturgia.getMetaLiturgia();
                        Himno himno = hi.getHimno();
                        Log.d("lorem",mMeta.getFecha());
                        setValue((T) mLiturgia);
                        Log.d("__get",dataSnapshot.toString());
                    });
                } else {
                    Log.d("__get","noTdataSnapshot.toString()");
                }
            });



        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        Log.d(TAG,"acg");
        //launchFirestore(1);
        super.onActive();
        registration = docRef.addSnapshotListener(eventListenerBis);

        //registration = docRef.addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        if (!hasActiveObservers()) {
            registration.remove();
            registration = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"wasremoved");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personalmente considero que este livedata en realidad es un ApiDatasource y la lógica que necesitas hacer es lógica de repositorio, pudiendo inyectar el repositorio dónde lo necesites.  De todas formas, igual MediatorLiveData te resuelve lo que quieres hacer, creando otro livedata para la segunda llamada, pero lo dicho, yo haría un repository pattern.

Comment: @ManuelMato tu comentario ha sido muy iluminador, pues no había pensado en algo así como un DataSource. El repository pattern sí lo estoy implementando, e incluso UseCases para las llamadas a mi servidor remoto, pero no tengo claro cómo incorporar los datos que provienen de Firestore. ¿Te refieres quizá a [algo como esto](https://github.com/Musfick/ChatApp-MVVM-Dagger2-RxJava-Firestore/blob/63e497e7d317d717c3a9ae5bef4c79fe4dd62ea7/app/src/main/java/com/foxhole/chatappmvvmdagger2rxjavafirestore/dataSource/remote/FirebaseDataSource.java)?

Comment: Mi idea es, en un futuro, traer los datos a una base de datos (Room) para que la App funcione sin conexión. Mientras puedo hacerlo, estoy trabajando con dos fuentes de datos (Firestore y Api remota). Ya tengo funcionando la Api remota con Retrofit y quisiera ahora incorporar a Firestore. La idea es: si un dato no está en Firestore, que lo busque en la Api remota (mi sitio web). Ahora funciona así, pero sin arquitectura limpia, llamando a Firestore o a Volley desde cada Activity.

Comment: Pues el ejemplo que subes está bastante bien, teniendo en cuenta lo que queires hacer un repositorio me parece una buena solución,  e inyectándole los datasources que necesites, uno que comunique con la api y otro que comunique con la base de datos y ahí harás la lógica de acceso a los datos, primero a firestore, después a tu api, guardar en firestore (y aquí podrías decidir devolver lo guardado)